# How to hide the site panel in powerBI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a sites panel down under. But how to hide it if I want to watch the Dashboard in the browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hide all pages the panel will disappear. Right click each page, and click "Hide"

[image: example]

Comment: The first pages are always visiable. I want hide the panel complete

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand the question. If you hide all pages (right-click every page and hide one by one) then the left-hand-side panel should disappear completely when you view the dashboard in PowerBi-service.

Comment: I want to view it in PowerBI Report-Server